# When and how to encode/decode HTML when interacting with a database?

Tags: php, html, sql, database, html-encode

I have a website which runs on PHP and a MySQL database. I was wondering how to best treat user input in regard to HTML encoding (I am well aware that I should store as received and decode in output: that's what I do) and this cycle in particular:

- user registers filling in a form with a username field, the content of the field is validated and sent and stored in the DB *as is* (no HTML encoding) as it will be required to output HTML, XML, JSON, plaintext and other formats;
- on any page requiring the username to be shown, it will be fetched from the database, HTML-encoded and displayed in the page;
- on a particular page the username is placed in the "value" field of an html text input: obviously this means that the username must be HTML encoded (otherwise XSS and  all those fantastic things...). However this also means that if the original username was "però" the text field will be `<input value="per&ograve;">` and when the user submits it the server will receive `per&ograve;` instead of `però`.

Now my question is: should the server decode all the received inputs so that `per&ograve;` gets decoded to the original `però`?
My doubt is that this would mean that if an user inputs `&egrave;` as his username it will be registered as `è` and not as he actually intended...

I know this is not such a big problem (don't know of many users which would want to use HTML special characters encoding literals in their usernames...), but it puzzled me and I could not find a completely satisfying solution.

Comment: Store as submitted. Escape for output, and escape *always* unless there's a really damned good reason. Your escaping may have a bug - you always want the original, as-submitted data available.

Comment: `However this also means that if the original usenrame was "però" the text field will be <input value="per&ograve;"> and when the user submits it the server will receive per&ograve; instead of però` That is not true.

Comment: @SLaks would you please elaborate on that?

Comment: You should not store any html in the database (I know that is not possible), but as little as possible. You should sanitize as much data as possible and make sure the user only insert HTML that you allow. Use strip_tags(), str_replace and some regex to get it all. And save username and other "clean" data as is.

Comment: I am aware that I should not store any HTML in my database (and that is what I do).  
My question wha how should I manage the output of my database (HTML encoded) being fed as input. If I should not store any HTML it means that I should decode it before storing it, but htis means that an user entering html valid code (like per&ograve;) will get his username cahnged

Comment: No, don't do anything to it before storing it. If they submit HTML and you accept it, store the HTML.

Comment: @Bonvi Ulrik is incorrect. You store raw HTML in the database. You sanitize/escape it on **output**. Every major framework will have functionality making this easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I've misunderstood what you're asking, you seem to have the wrong impression about the effect of outputting HTML encoded strings into text inputs. Here's a basic example of what will happen. Let's say you have a user who wants to be named `PB&amp;J`. Sure, it's weird, but not everyone can pick a nice non-weird username like "Bonvi" or "Don't Panic".

So you save that in your database *as is.*

Later, when you're using it in another form, you escape it for output.

```
<input type="text" name="username" value="<?= htmlspecialchars($username) ?>">
```

In your page *source*, you'll see

```
<input type="text" name="username" value="PB&amp;amp;J">
```

with the ampersand converted to an HTML entity. (Which is what you want, in case they really wanted to be named `bob"><script>alert("però!")</script><p class="ha` or something worse.)

But the value displayed in the text box will be `PB&amp;J`, and when the user submits the form, the value in `$_POST['username']` will be `PB&amp;J`, *not* `PB&amp;amp;J`. **It will not be changed to the encoded value.**

(I used `htmlspecialchars` in this example, but the same would apply with your example using però with `htmlentities`.)

I'm trying to explain it basically, so I apologize if I did misunderstand you  - I don't intend to sound condescending.